# HTMLCollection в componentDidMount пустой

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходимо поместить в React-компонент HTML полученный извне и произвести с ним ряд манипуляций (навесить обработчики на ссылки). Для этого сделан простой компонент (см. ниже). Само навешивание обработчиков для простоты удалил из примера.
Проблема в том, что при печати в консоль будет непустой HTMLCollection link но всегда нулевая длина link.length.
Это признак того что в DOM элементы еще не помещены. Но по идее componentDidMount вызывается после рендеринга компонента и все уже должно быть в DOM.
В итоге навесить обработчики не получается.
Почему так происходит и каким образом навесить-таки обработчики?

```
class HTML extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var root = document.getElementById(this.props.id);
    var link = root.getElementsByTagName('a');
    console.dir(link); // several elements here
    console.log('LENGTH: ' + link.length); // but length always 0
  }

  render() {
    return (  
      <div id={this.props.id} className='html' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.data}} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: чтобы проверить  Ваше "по идее", воспользуйтесь setTimeout... дальше действуйте исходя из полученной информации

Comment: Это не мое "по идее" это документация по реакту :(

Comment: Проверить ничего не мешает.

Comment: Проверил. С таймаутом все работает.

Comment: а что за `html` вы вставляете?

Comment: `console` не самый честный способ подебажить, особенно объекты, массивы, так как может отображать не правильные данные

Comment: Да просто кусок html который запрашиваю с сервера.

Comment: какой то у вас не правильный реакт https://codesandbox.io/embed/fancy-glade-d66hi

Comment: Ну вот такой :(
Я сам в фидле пробовал - там тоже работает. Но если собирать на локальном компе, то не пашет.

Comment: Во Vue есть глобальный метод `nextTick`, который используется для работы с обновлённым DOM после изменения данных. Что-то типа setTimeout. Может в Реакте тоже такое есть?

Comment: версии одинаковые? как-то мало данных для того, что бы разобраться. Разные браузеры пробовали? Обновить версию реакта? Как компонент загружается и так далее

Comment: версия реакта 16.8.6
браузеры разные пробовал - везде так

Answer (score 0):

После рытья документации и экспериментов переписал все на использование Callback Refs
С этим механизмом все заработало.